# Getting error HTTP ERROR 404 in RESTlet framework

Tags: java, web-services, rest, restlet

hi i m new to restlet framework. I am just creating my first application but i m getting error as following:

HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /hellofourthtrial/hello. Reason: NOT_FOUND

My code goes as follow:

---

### HelloWorldResource.java

```
package hellofourthtrial;

import org.restlet.resource.Get;
import org.restlet.resource.ServerResource;

public class HelloWorldResource extends ServerResource{

    @Get
    public String represent() {
        return "in the represent";
    }

}
```

---

### FirstStepsApplication.java

```
package hellofourthtrial;

import org.restlet.Application;
import org.restlet.Restlet;
import org.restlet.data.Protocol;
import org.restlet.routing.Router;
import org.restlet.Server;

public class FirstStepsApplication extends Application{

    /**
     * Creates a root Restlet that will receive all incoming calls.
     */
    @Override
    public synchronized Restlet createInboundRoot() {
        // Create a router Restlet that routes each call to a
        // new instance of HelloWorldResource.
        Router router = new Router(getContext());
        // Defines only one route
        router.attach("/hello", HelloWorldResource.class);
        return router;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
          Server server = new Server(Protocol.HTTP, 8888);
          server.setNext(new FirstStepsApplication());
          server.start();

          System.out.println("Press a key to stop");
          System.in.read();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
```

### }

### web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.restlet.application</param-name>
    <param-value>
        hellofourthtrial.FirstStepsApplication
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.restlet.ext.servlet.ServerServlet
    </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RestletServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have developed this project in eclipse and i m running it as web application. I get following output in the console when i run it as web app

```
May 12, 2011 11:22:23 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
May 12, 2011 11:22:23 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Admin\workspace2\HelloFourthTrial\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
May 12, 2011 11:22:23 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Admin\workspace2\HelloFourthTrial\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
May 12, 2011 4:52:24 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

I m really stuck, i cant figure out where am i going wrong. Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When you call the application, try `http://localhost:8888/HelloFourthTrial/hello` in your URL.

Comment: If you running it in eclipse then the content root may be the name of the eclipse project - and it WILL be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you bind 'HelloFourthTrial' to the path... Have you tried accessing the URL without that substring (= http://localhost:8888/hello)?

Comment: ya i have tried with the URL you mentioned, but i m still getting the same error